# What are these suffixes used after the call sign?

Tags: air-traffic-control, call-sign

I often play a flight simulator game Infinite Flight (http://www.infinite-flight.com) on my iPhone. The game lets you choose the following suffixes with your call sign.

1. Heavy
2. Super
3. Flight of 2
4. Flight of 4
5. Flight of 5
6. Flight of 6
7. Flight of 7
8. Flight of 8
9. Flight of 9
10. Flight of 10

I am aware what "Heavy" means but now aware about the rest. Can someone let me know?

Thanks

Comment: you may rather like to ask this question [here](https://web.facebook.com/groups/infiniteflightfangroup/?fref=ts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heavy - all aircraft with maximum take-off weight greater than 300,000lbs (whether or not they're operating at that weight) It's to highlight to the controller that wake turbulence could be a problem for a following aircraft.

Super - Airbus A380: As for 'Heavy', but more so.

Flight of X - All the rest relate to groups or formations containing that number of aircraft.

These originate in the FAA regulations and are summarised on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_sign#FAA_aircraft_identification_regulations)

There are a number of other unusual suffixes including 'Concorde' (used only by British Airways for the now retired Concorde), Lifeguard (for medical flights), and others

Comment: what about the rest.

Comment: I quote: _'All the rest relate to groups or formations containing that number of aircraft.'_

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by "All the rest relate to groups or formations containing that number of aircraft"

Comment: Sorry - what is unclear? Flight of 2 - a group or formation of two aircraft, and so on.

Comment: ok.. something like in Airshows?

Comment: why would the game let you have Flight of X suffixes. At a time you are only flying one plane.. Strange!!

Comment: An air show might be one example, but it could be used at any time when two or more aircraft are travelling together. I can't comment on your game, though.

Comment: Will "commercial airplanes" ever travel together. Can you give an example..

Comment: Commercial aeroplanes are subject to all sorts of rules regarding separation, so it's unlikely they'd ever use 'Flight of...'. A flying club rally might consist of several light aircraft on some sort of social event and might fly together.

Comment: so Antonov An-225 should also be super??

Comment: @Ank: There already is a question about that here. But yes, the *Super* suffix was originally created for the A380, but it makes no sense to not apply it to the An-225, which has a similar wake.

Comment: @Ank, in passenger operation they would not be allowed to, but for presentation purposes Airbus [did it with A350s](http://aviationweek.com/commercial-aviation/video-airbus-a350-900-formation-flight). Note that since formation flight relies on all the other pilots seeing the leading aircraft, it basically can only be done under VFR.